# Test multiple .equals() at once

Tags: java, equals

I wanted to know if there was a way to shorten this if statement with the ".equals" so that I can test things in one line, instead of multiple if statements.

This is an excerpt my current long winded code. (This is what I want to shorten)

```
if (queryArray[1].equals("+")) { 
     System.out.println("Got +");
 } else if (queryArray[1].equals("-")) {
     System.out.println("Got -");
 } else if (queryArray[1].equals("*")) {
     System.out.println("Got *");
 }
```

I tried doing this (Does not work) to reduce the number of lines needed.

```
if (queryArray[1].equals("+","-","*")) { 
             System.out.println("Got +");
         }
```

And even (Does not work):

```
if (queryArray[1].equals("+" || "-" || "*")) { 
         System.out.println("Got +");
     }
```

Also, I know about the or syntax "`||`" within `if statements`, however I'm looking to shorten it within the "`.equals()`" method.

Is there any way to shorten this code? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're only doing single-character comparisons, you can do a `switch` on `queryArray[1].charAt(0)`.

```
switch (queryArray[1].charAt(0)) {
    case '+':
      // plus thing
      break;
    case '-':
      // minus thing
      break
    // ... and so on
}
```

Or if you're using Java 7, you can switch directly on the string.

Answer (score 2):

First off your *alternative* syntax inside the `.equals()` isn't valid Java.

Unless you have way more than a few tests and each one of them has lots of [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) in each condition, there isn't any compelling reason to do what you are asking.

That said, you need to flip the problem on its head and do something like the following:

```
interface Handler { public void handle(); }

final Map<String, Handler> symbols = new HashMap<String, Handler>();
symbols.put("+", new Handler() {
    public void handle() { System.out.println("Got +"); }
};   
symbols.put("-", new Handler() {
    public void handle() { System.out.println("Got -"); }
};
symbols.put("*", new Handler() {
    public void handle() { System.out.println("Got *"); }
};
```

Then the logic tests are reduced to:

```
symbols.get(queryArray[1]).handle();
```

This won't be any faster than the individual `if/elseif/else` construct, but it does something like you are looking for to reduce the lines of code.

This is a common Object Oriented Design pattern, it is a variation on the [Chain of Responsibility Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

It is very useful when there are many alternatives in an `if/elseif/else` construct and the logic in each alternative is complicated.

It makes adding alternatives simple as implementing the interface and adding the alternative to the `Map`.

It also makes maintenance a very easy as well. Because it promotes Encapsulation of the rules and Cohesion of the logic. Something that is gets completely lost in very large `if/elseif/else` blocks.

*You don't have to use `Anonymous Inner Classes` as in my example, they can be regular classes that are in their own files or regular Inner Classes.*

Answer (score 2):

With Java 7, you can do a `switch` on strings:

```
switch(queryArray[1]) {
  case "+":
  case "*":
  case "-":
     System.out.println("Got " + queryArray[1]);
     break;
  default:
     // do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can even do it in this way

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("+","-","*");

if(list.contains(queryArray[1]))
  System.out.println("Got "+queryArray[1]);
```

Comment: Will the JRE optimizing compiler work out that its not necessary to create a list here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Map<String,String> resultMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
resultMap.put("+","Got +");
resultMap.put("-","Got -");
resultMap.put("*","Got *");

System.out.println(resultMap.get(queryArray[1]));
```

Comment: not the prettiest way for the given example with three cases, but in a larger number of cases this actually is a neat solution, IMHO :)

Answer (score 0):

The code block you provided is the most effecient and more readable. and if considered scalabilty and maintenance, it shouldn't be refactore if logic doesn't change.

```
if (queryArray[1].equals("+")) 
{       
    System.out.println("Got +");  
} 
else if (queryArray[1].equals("-")) 
{      
    System.out.println("Got -");  
}
else if (queryArray[1].equals("*")) 
{
    System.out.println("Got *");  
}
```

However **Borealid** has given `switch-case` construct but a little bit of logic change will initiate a lot of changes and probably bugs-crawling also.

Well, I'm too providing a solution on same lines, but it's also not better than the code you provided:

```
System.out.println(queryArray[1].equals("+")?"Got +"
                  :queryArray[1].equals("-")?"Got -"
                  :queryArray[1].equals("*")?"Got *"
                  :"");
```

if your problem is that method size is increasing, try creating a separate method which returns a string (to be printed), so the equals-comparison method can be moved to a separate block.

And, one more thing to say, the `||` and `&&` operators should be used with `boolean` operands. and, before calling an API check it's javadoc: [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 0):

The shortest Java-solution I can think of is:

```
System.out.println (Arrays.asList ("+", "-", "*").contains ("-"));
```

Answer (score 0):

On a single line ...

```
if (Arrays.asList("+", "-", "*").contains(queryArray[1])) {
    System.out.println("BINGO!");
}
```

This works because `asList` has a varargs parameter.

However, this code involves creating and initializing a new `String[]`, wrapping it in a new `List` and then iterating over the list.  So don't do it if performance is likely to be a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Something even more obscure:

```
char a = queryArray[1].charAt(0);
if ((a - '*') * (a - '+') * (a - '-') == 0) {
    /* process here. */
}
```

Rather useless if you want to compare more than one character, though.